# Can not get UITableView to Display NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sounds like a question that has been answered... maybe but i have checked all of the possible solutions i believe and nothing will work for me.

My .h file looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface epsMenuPage : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
NSArray *listData;
...
UITableView *menuList;
...
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *listData;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *menuList;
...
@end
```

My .m file looks like this

```
@implementation epsMenuPage
@synthesize listData;
...
@synthesize menuList;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
//Arrays credit,debit and both
creditListData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Return",@"Force Sale",@"Authorize    Only",@"Total Sales",@"Items Sold",@"Reciept's", nil];
debitListData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Return",@"Force Sale",@"Authorize Only",@"Total Sales",@"Items Sold",@"Reciept's", nil];
bothListData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Batch History",@"Settle Batch", nil];
self.listData = creditListData;
[menuList reloadData];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.view.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:95/255.0 blue:95/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[colorChange setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:95/255.0 blue:95/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.view addSubview:creditTabButton];
[self.view addSubview:debitTabButton];
[self.view addSubview:bothTabButton];
[self.view addSubview:creditButtonText];
[self.view addSubview:debitButtonText];
[self.view addSubview:bothBottonText];
[self.view addSubview:colorChange];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setTitleBAckButton:nil];
[self setTitleSettingsButton:nil];
[self setCreditTabButton:nil];
[self setDebitTabButton:nil];
[self setBothTabButton:nil];
[self setMenuList:nil];
[self setColorChange:nil];
[self setCreditButtonText:nil];
[self setDebitButtonText:nil];
[self setBothBottonText:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.listData count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"tableID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listData objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;

    }

- (void)dealloc {
[titleBAckButton release];
[titleSettingsButton release];
[creditTabButton release];
[debitTabButton release];
[bothTabButton release];
[menuList release];
[colorChange release];
[creditButtonText release];
[debitButtonText release];
[bothBottonText release];
[listData release];
[super dealloc];
}
 - (IBAction)titleBackClick:(id)sender {
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)titleSettingsClick:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)creditTabClick:(id)sender {
self.listData = creditListData;
[menuList reloadData];
[colorChange setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:95/255.0 blue:95/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.view addSubview:creditTabButton];
[self.view addSubview:creditButtonText];
[self.view addSubview:colorChange];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:95/255.0 blue:95/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (IBAction)debitTabClick:(id)sender {
self.listData = debitListData;
[menuList reloadData];
[colorChange setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:244/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:33/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.view addSubview:debitTabButton];
[self.view addSubview:debitButtonText];
[self.view addSubview:colorChange];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:33/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (IBAction)bothTabClick:(id)sender {
self.listData = bothListData;
[menuList reloadData];
[colorChange setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:72/255.0 green:72/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.view addSubview:bothTabButton];
[self.view addSubview:bothBottonText];
[self.view addSubview:colorChange];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:72/255.0 green:72/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
@end
```

I really for the life of me can not figure out why it wont display to my TableView, i have tried so many different tutorials.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you not configured connections for tableView <-> menuList, tableView delegate or tableView datasource in InterfaceBuilder (xib) file?

Comment: i double checked and made sure it was linked and it is, still no data to my NSarray.

Comment: I didn't see any property declarations, so I assumed there were no `IBOutlet` but this could definitely be why.

Comment: In your code, I don't see a point where you programmatically add menuList as a subview to your UIViewController's view NOR do I see an IBOutlet associated with menuList (added in interface builder). One or other of these would be required.

Comment: Does it even stop at the data source methods for `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`? Set a breakpoint.

Comment: @LucasTizma no, it doesnt stop there...How can i get it to stop?

Comment: If it doesn't stop there, then it's never being called, which means your data source is **not** set correctly. Show up a screen shot of your IB configuration and triple check the outlets. Also, show us your entire .h file.

Answer (score 1):

You're never adding the `menuList` table view to your view. Add it and see if that does the trick:

```
// In -viewDidLoad

[self.view addSubview:menuList];
```

**EDIT 1**: Did you declare properties in your .h? These aren't visible, so it appears as if you're not creating or adding your table view to the view controller's view. However, if you are using `IBOutlet`s, then this probably isn't the issue.

**EDIT 2**: From the comments below, your `dataSource` is nil, which is exactly why nothing is being displayed. Make sure your table view in Interface Builder has its `dataSource` outlet pointing to your view controller. To be double sure, delete the table view from Interface Builder and add it back again. Make sure your connections are exactly right. Also try cleaning the project and rebuilding, as well as restarting Xcode.

Comment: Added this to my project and still no Change in the Data being Loaded to my NSArray.

Comment: But have you created a tableView? If you log the value of menuList what does it say. Add NSLog(@"menuList: %@", menuList). If it's null, then you'll need to create it in your viewDidLoad or sort out your IBOutlets.

Comment: i did add more to my .h file in my post @Matthew Elton i have a IBoutlet for my UITableView *menuList;

Comment: Please put a breakpoint in `-viewDidLoad` and log `menuList` as @MatthewElton suggested. Is it nil?

Comment: when logged this is my return: <UITableView: 0x632ea00; frame = (20 117; 280 343); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6830b60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: sorry @MatthewElton didn't understand what you asked.

Comment: Also log the table view's `dataSource`.

Comment: my dataSource returns: (
    Return,
    "Force Sale",
    "Authorize Only",
    "Total Sales",
    "Items Sold",
    "Reciept's"
)
which happens to be right.

Comment: No, the table view's data source... `NSLog(@"dataSource: %@", menuList.dataSource);`

Comment: Given all that's gone on here, I'd also double check the you've set the tableView delegate too. (Check you connection in IB and NSLog(@"tableViewDelegate: %@", menuList.delegate); to make sure you're 100% confident it is set up.)

Comment: Well yes, having the `delegate` set is always good as well, but the `dataSource` is all that's needed to get data display.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are missing the required datasource method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; {
  return 1;
}
```

Also, it looks like you are not actually initializing your `UIButton`'s, or anything you are adding as a subview. Are you using a nib?

Comment: The default value is 1, so this isn't the issue. I believe the issue is that the table view is never added as a subview.

Comment: You cannot assume default value to 1. As Apple's documentation does not discuss about that..  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You must implement  numberOfSectionsinTableView with return value to 1

Comment: i have told that method to return the count from listData and the listData count will change when the buttons are pushed to a different array....Still the Array will not display on my TableView List. return [self.listData count];

Comment: The documentation does say what you can assume. Return Value: "The number of sections in tableView. The default value is 1."